# svg-sprite-loader with Angular 8 custom webpack config

Tags: webpack, angular8, svg-sprite

I am trying to use svg-sprite-loader package (to create a svg sprite) with my Angular 8 project using custom webpack config.

I am using below custom config:

```
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(svg)$/,
                loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                options: {
                    spriteFilename: './src/assets/svg/combinedicons.svg',
                    runtimeCompat: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new SpriteLoaderPlugin({
        plainSprite: true,
        }),
    ],
};
```

I am getting following error while running ng build:

> Cannot find module 'webpack/package.json'
>   Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/package.json'

I am not able to identify where the issue is, is it with my config or the package itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to install Webpack as an explicit dependency via `npm i -D webpack`.

Or you might have 2 different versions of Webpack installed.

Run `npm ls webpack`.

You should see something like this:

```
user$ npm ls webpack
@my-app /Users/user/my-app
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.9
│ └── webpack@4.29.0  deduped
└── webpack@4.29.0
```

If you have different versions of webpack try npm installing a version of webpack that matches that of the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` dependency.

If you have the CLI installed globally it's also worth checking if you have multiple versions of Webpack installed globally.

I believe you can run `npm ls -g webpack`.