# Is there a way to setup a custom svg icon library in a Angular project without using <mat-icon> tag?

Tags: angular, svg, frontend, icons, material-design

I'm working on a project where the customer have send a custom svg iconset.

Is there a way to set up a custom svg icon library which uses a tag that works like the  tag, at the frontend?

It's a Angular project but we don't want to use Angular Material.

Comment: Nobody forces you to use a certain library. Does this answer your question? [svg-sprite-loader with Angular 8 custom webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58520617/svg-sprite-loader-with-angular-8-custom-webpack-config) Or does that [module](https://github.com/jannicz/ng-svg-icon-sprite) help?

Comment: If you are comfortable with creating SVG; I created https://iconmeister.github.io/ to work with different Icon Sets (now has 7000+ icons). The end result is **a single Custom Element file** with only the icons you use/specify.

Comment: There's a really great tutorial on medium for this: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-create-an-icon-library-in-angular-4f8863d95a